# Proving inexistence of limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove that limit does not exist
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
Obviously, since it is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, classic approach of substituing $x$ as a "simple" function - linear, polynomial, etc. Won't work. Polar gives us a reasonable answer 
$r\sin\theta\cos\theta$. How would I easily show it does not exist?

Comment: Use $|xy|/\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq |y|$ to show that the limit exist.

Comment: Sorry, it does exist, I thought of another one I've already proven, I should get some sleep.

Comment: @user74200 It happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 3):

Using $$\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$$ we have that

$$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{xy}\rightarrow 0$$

so the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense when $xy<0$. It's perhaps better (for more applications) to bound the numerator instead.

Answer (score 2):

As $(x,y)\to0$, we know $r\to0$, but $\sin\theta\cos\theta$ is bounded, so the limit *does* exist; it's zero.

One can plot the graph for verification.